# Which cordova plugin can be make background service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, messenger

I'm creating messenger app using ionic & xmpp & openfire.

I'll add background service when I receive message then push notification.

So, I still find plugin or example.

katzer/backgroundMode plugins is not enough..because this plugin can't when I close app swipe up my Iphone.

It just can be make background/foreground..maybe.

Which plugin can wake up my app if I received message.

Finally I want create like this,

user send message to me -> openfire -> offline message (because app closed on my mobile) or online message (this is not problem) -> find user -> push notification my mobile -> received message.

Answer (score 0):

for push notification you can use [Urban Airship](http://docs.urbanairship.com/) push notification. It is available for both android and ios. Check out the link.

1. [Android](http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/android.html)
2. [IOS](http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/ios.html)
3. [Cordova / Phonegap](http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/phonegap.html)